# Could I apply list filter in Firebase Database Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Could I apply list filter like `startAt(...)`, `endAt(...)`, `equalsTo(...)`
by adding something in database link in Firebase Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database console does not have an option to filter the data.

It's an interesting idea though, so you might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).